# Inclusion of Mycoplasma synoviae vaccine strain MSH into CLueGO for Ontology and Pathway mapping

Tags: cytoscape

I have done some RNAseq studies using Mycoplasma synoviae vaccine strain MSH and would like to perform analysis using ClueGO and CLuePedia. Would it be possible for this strain to be added to the organism list please?

Comment: As interesting as this is, it is not something SO can help with. Contacting the authors is the right way to go. Voting to close for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reach out to the ClueGO authors directly.  They are usually quite responsive, but I don't think they monitor Stack Overflow.